# WordPress add_rewrite_rule for user login in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'd like to be able to use a user's login name in my URL, and then grab it for use within the page template. Like this:

> mywebsite.com/admin/users/user/{user_login}

I've tried the following, but the query_var doesn't get added to the query and the match is always stripped from the end of the URL, like this:

> mywebsite.com/admin/users/user/login-name/ -->
>   mywebsite.com/admin/users/user/

I know the rewrite is happening, because it successfully takes me to the "user" page, but I just can't seem to get the user login to come with it.

```
/* add query var */

function add_user_query_vars($query_vars){

    $query_vars[] = 'user_login';

    return $query_vars;

}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_user_query_vars');

/* add rewrite rule */

function add_user_rewrite_rules($rules){

    $user_rules = array('admin/users/user/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=user&user_login=$matches[1]');

    $rules = $user_rules + $rules;

    return $rules;

}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_user_rewrite_rules');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the permalinks? That may work with this.

Comment: Yeah, I flush the permalinks by reloading the permalinks page from the wp dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

You have to include the full page hierarchy in the pagename parameter. In my case, it is admin/users/user, so my rewrite looks like this, and after a flush of the rewrite rules, it is working as expected.

```
$user_rules = array('admin/users/user/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=admin/users/user&user_login=$matches[1]');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it in an `.htaccess` file?

Add this to the `.htaccess` file in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/users/user/([^/]+)/? index.php?pagename=user&user_login=$1 [DPI,L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files.

Comment: Yeah, the same issue happens if I do it via .htacces. Could there be another WP rewrite rule overriding it?

Comment: Is the `admin` folder immediately below the folder where you put the `.htaccess`?

Comment: admin is top-most parent page. admin > users > user -- all pages.